# How do I properly encode foreign accented characters in ASP.NET MVC/SQL application (C-R-U examples please)

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the best practice for reading/saving/updating accented characters via HTML/MVC/LINQ-to-SQL?

We have a web application where users submit articles from all over the world.  Some users, particularly those in Europe, submit articles with accented/extended characters.   We are using Linq to SQL, C#, SQL 2005.  All our db tables are normalized and Linq to SQL is used as the data mapping layer.

The bug we want to fix is that in our MVC3 / SQL 2005 application, accented characters in words submitted by users via the normal

```
using (Html.BeginForm()) {... }
```

block to an [HttpPost] attributed controller are rendered as '?' on the Save event.  For example, all works well until foreign characters are entered, in which case we might have a record that talks about "Proven?al activities" in the db.

What is the best practice for encoding these in an MVC3, SQL2005-ish way?

I would really appreciate it if someone outlined the create, read and update operations for something like this, or tell me what magic thing I'm missing.  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

- nvarchar types (not varchar)
- literals with the N prefix eg `WHERE x = N'foo'`

Example: only N prefix + nvarchar saves OK

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (Broken varchar(10), Working nvarchar(10))
INSERT @test VALUES (N'Value 化化', N'Value 化化')
INSERT @test VALUES ('Value ける', 'Value ける')

SELECT * FROM @test
```

There is no global magic setting either...

Edit:

I'd also run SQL profiler to see if you are sending characters
I now suspect you're breaking things before it hits the database.

Taking Western European (DE+FR+Nordics) it works OK without my suggestions above

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (NowWorking varchar(10), Working nvarchar(10))
INSERT @test VALUES (N'öéäàüè', N'öéäàüè')
INSERT @test VALUES ('öéäàüè', 'öéäàüè')

SELECT * FROM @test
```

Comment: Brilliant and incredibly fast.  Boy do I love the community of StackOverflow.  Thank you so much; hope to return the favor some day.